# Can't add generated ssh key to ssh agent "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, terminal, github

Firstly, yes, I read similar questions and answers here and on stackoverflow. It didn't seem to give any visible result so I'm making a new question.

I am using the latest Debian Buster and trying to set up access to GitHub from the terminal.
I follow the steps to set up ssh connection on the official GitHub site [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

```
user@home-machine ~ $ sudo ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email"
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/ed25519): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [I don't use passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/ed25519.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/ed25519.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx my@email
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+----[SHA256]-----+

user@home-machine ~ $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 2864
user@home-machine ~ $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
user@home-machine ~ $ sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#here is me being stupid and not seeing the correct path, bu I amended the mistake below
user@home-machine ~ $ sudo ssh-add root/.ssh/id_ed25519
[sudo] password for user:
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Why is it not working? What am I doing wrong?
Sorry, I'm just learning Linux and git and could be missing something.
I would appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**
Tried to execute commands:

```
debtop@DebTop:~$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
2864
debtop@DebTop:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-wpXiIKBOY4x7/agent.2863
debtop@DebTop:~$ eval$(ssh-agent -s)
bash: evalSSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yUWON3uD5kT5/agent.4242;: File or directory doesn't exist
```

Comment: The problem most likely arises because you don't have correct permissions to load the keyfile. Either become `root` completely (`sudo -i`) or create the key as your normal user. Why do you even use `sudo` to create the key? That is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all keys and tried to pass the whole procedure again.
It did work when I created keys without `sudo` as in:

```
user@home-machine ~ $ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email"
```

Thanks to @Panki for the tip. Don't remember, why was I using `sudo` to create keys.

Comment: Also note that the `|` in `-C |"my@email"` ought to be an issue as it introduces a pipe in the command line end tries to run your email address as a command (and `-C` won't get an argument). Please consider updating it to the command that you are actually using.

Comment: I think the pipe was a typo when I copied it from the terminal to the question. Thank for the info anyway.

Comment: @VladimirMarkiev, you can [edit] the posts here to fix typos like that

Answer (score 4):

```
user@home-machine ~ $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 2864
```

Here you're starting the `ssh-agent` as `user`. This initializes the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable which is used by the other SSH tools to find the Unix socket for the agent.

```
user@home-machine ~ $ sudo ssh-add root/.ssh/id_ed25519
[sudo] password for user:
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

And here you invoke `ssh-add` as `root`. Unless you have explicitly configured `sudo` to pass the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable across the sudo transition, it by default **will not transfer** it to `root`'s environment.

Without the environment variable, the `ssh-add` command will not be able to find the `ssh-agent` socket, as it is located in a randomly-named sub-directory (typically `/tmp/ssh-<random_alphabet_soup>/agent.<number>`). The socket and the directory it's in is also only accessible by the original `user`, but usually that's not a problem for root.

If you want the agent to work across the `sudo` transition for this user specifically, you would need to add something like this to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults:user env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

(Replace `user` with the actual username, of course.)

If you want it to work for all users when they're transitioning to root using `sudo`, you could do it this way:

```
Defaults>root env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```